# How can I change the key of an existing object in a NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

How can I change the key of an existing object in a NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: You don't need to update your question to include the answer. The answers are good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to remove the object from the original key and add it back with the new key.  You could turn this into a category on `NSMutableDictionary`.

The category would look something like this:

```
@interface NSMutableDictionary (RenameKey)

- (void)renameKey:(NSString *)original to:(NSString *)new;

@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionary (RenameKey)

- (void)renameKey:(id)original to:(id)new; {
    id value = [self objectForKey:original];
    [self removeObjectForKey:original];
    [self setObject:value forKey:new];}
@end
```

You should probably add a pre/postfix to the method name to avoid future name conflicts in the runtime.  The above is also not thread-safe, it takes three steps to perform the rename.